# Fail to decrypt LUKS partition

Tags: luks, manjaro

I was trying to put a ntfs partition to mount at boot and I have used the gnome-disks for this. I selected the partition ntfs and alter the configs to mount at boot. After that I rebooted the system and when is asked for input password to decrypt /home partition some failure occurs. I’m sure the password is correct. I’ve found at journal -xb command result the folowing error:

***Fail to activate with a keyfile: '/crypto_keyfile.bin' Invalid argument***

My lsblk command result:

```
[manjaro-gnome /]# lsblk -o name,uuid,mountpoint
NAME                                          UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0                                                                              /run/miso/sfs/livefs
loop1                                                                              /run/miso/sfs/mhwdfs
loop2                                                                              /run/miso/sfs/desktopfs
loop3                                                                              /run/miso/sfs/rootfs
sda                                                                                
├─sda1                                        2E6B-B242                            
├─sda2                                        B48F-011C                            
├─sda3                                        a16ce210-e958-40bf-843a-60d659472f57 /repchroot
├─sda4                                        d5a167c6-93ce-4a2a-9ff6-1010f0674eaf 
├─sda5                                                                             
├─sda6                                        DC0E00690E003ED0                     
└─sda7                                        77286FD753707FDC                     
sdb                                           2018-04-28-08-00-50-00               
├─sdb1                                        2018-04-28-08-00-50-00               /run/miso/bootmnt
└─sdb2                                        8955-B080                            
nvme0n1                                                                            
├─nvme0n1p1                                   F382-3817                            
├─nvme0n1p2                                   123a2f7d-e658-41d1-b42c-cb3ec3b3d5c4 
├─nvme0n1p3                                   6158a5ba-e5d6-4955-95c7-2eb5ad109a7b /
└─nvme0n1p4                                   0330bdcc-3bf2-4c83-8b1d-748a0bef9fe4 
  └─luks-0330bdcc-3bf2-4c83-8b1d-748a0bef9fe4 466c08d3-d7f4-4ee7-b313-83e0c8dbd030
```

My fstab command result:

```
[manjaro-gnome /]# cat etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=F382-3817                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults,noatime 0 2
UUID=6158a5ba-e5d6-4955-95c7-2eb5ad109a7b /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
/dev/mapper/luks-0330bdcc-3bf2-4c83-8b1d-748a0bef9fe4 /home          ext4    defaults,noatime 0 2
UUID=123a2f7d-e658-41d1-b42c-cb3ec3b3d5c4 swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 2
UUID=283610a5-2faa-4382-ae4f-71575533e846 swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 2
/dev/sda7 /mnt/sda7 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

And my crypttab command result:

```
[manjaro-gnome /]# cat etc/crypttab
# /etc/crypttab: mappings for encrypted partitions.
#
# Each mapped device will be created in /dev/mapper, so your /etc/fstab
# should use the /dev/mapper/<name> paths for encrypted devices.
#
# See crypttab(5) for the supported syntax.
#
# NOTE: Do not list your root (/) partition here, it must be set up
#       beforehand by the initramfs (/etc/mkinitcpio.conf). The same applies
#       to encrypted swap, which should be set up with mkinitcpio-openswap
#       for resume support.
#
# <name>               <device>                         <password> <options>
luks-0330bdcc-3bf2-4c83-8b1d-748a0bef9fe4 UUID=0330bdcc-3bf2-4c83-8b1d-748a0bef9fe4     /crypto_keyfile.bin luks
```

There is no /crypto_keyfile.bin file at my root directory.
I found this topic that has a possible solution, but I’m not sure if is same problem that I have:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/decryption-problem/25284/18

Comment: First of all, please remove the line you added to fstab, and reboot your system. then test if the created partition is accessible by old fashion way or not (check it ask you for password and you can add or remove files inside it).

Comment: @HamidYousefi I tryied to remove the last line added in fstab and same problem occurs. Is asked to put the password and after that a fail occours again. I've booted using live and I can manually decrypt the partition and write files inside her.

Comment: If when you removed the line from fstab, and then it worked properly (you had access to open and add or remove files inside it), it is an issue that I can help you with an answer. but if after removing the line from fstab, you can't open this partition, in that case you must recreate it, and please dont use NTFS, it is not good option for using with Linux base file systems or related tools.

Comment: After remove the last line of fstab I still can't decrypt my LUKS partition (/home). During the boot is asked for the password and after type it, the problem "Fail to activate with a keyfile: '/crypto_keyfile.bin' Invalid argument" occurs again.
My root and home partition are ext4. This NTFS (sda7) partition is used for store data for both Windows and Linux.
I can write data in /home when I boot using live and decrypt manualy the partition using command **cryptsetup luksOpen ...**.